# Conditional Formatting based on Option

Tags: output-formatting

Consider the function `Foo[symbol_String, opt:OptionsPattern[]]` which has as one of its options `Label` which defaults `None`.

My question is: how do I change the display format of this function so that if `Label` is `None`, then it is displayed as just `symbol` but if the `Label` is not `None`, then it becomes `Superscript[symbol, label]`?

As far as I know, there is no way to do pattern matching against anything in collected in `OptionsPattern` (though feel free to correct me); and using an `If` clause doesn't seem to work either as the second call to `OptionValue[Foo, Label]` seems to mess things up.

Here's the code of what I have tried:

```
Options[Foo] = {Label -> None};
Format[Foo[symbol_String, opt:OptionsPattern[]]] := 
  Superscript[symbol, OptionValue[Foo, Label]];
Format[Foo[symbol_String, opt:OptionsPattern[]]] := 
  If[OptionValue[Foo, Label] == None, 
   symbol, 
   Superscript[symbol, OptionValue[Foo, Label]]];
```

Comment: Would `Module[{lbl = OptionValue[Foo, Label]}, If[lbl === None, symbol, Superscript[symbol, lbl]]]` suit your needs?

Comment: @J.M. Well... that was rather simple and I probably should've tried it :/  If you want to write that as an answer and I'll accept it.  Also, why is the second call of `OptionValue` problematic?

Comment: Actually, it worked once but then displayed `lbl$1067`.  I'm confused as to what's going on.  EDIT:  My bad, I missed the `===` (I wrote `==` instead).

Comment: "why is the second call of `OptionValue` problematic" - this is more of trying not to do the same thing more than once, actually. With respect to the weird display, then it would seem your minimal example is a bit too minimal; try to come up with an example where this problem of yours shows up.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks (the weird display was my mistake as mentioned above).  Feel free to write up the answer and I'll accept it (or this question can be closed if it doesn't really belong here).

Comment: @JP-Ellis, out of curiosity why do you wrap your function names with `Format`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to set the default value of the `Label` option to an empty string,

```
Options[Foo] = {Label -> ""};
Foo[symbol_String, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Superscript[symbol, OptionValue[Label]]

Foo["bob"]
Foo["bob", Label -> "does not care for these jokes"]
```

[image]

```
Options[Foo] = {Label -> None};
Foo[symbol_String, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Superscript[symbol, 
  If[OptionValue[Label] === None, "", OptionValue[Label]]]
```

gives the same output.

Or, with no empty superscript,

```
Options[Foo] = {Label -> None};
Foo[symbol_String, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[OptionValue[Label] === None, symbol, 
  Superscript[symbol, OptionValue[Label]]]
```

Again, same results

Comment: I considered doing that; however, I intend to export things to TeX often and unfortunately `Foo["\[Phi]"] // TeXForm` gives `\phi ^{\text{}}` which isn't ideal.

Comment: Jason, if you want, you have my express permission to expand on what I wrote in the comments. ;) Oops, apparently you did it already; maybe use `Module[]` like I did in the comments to avoid duplication of effort?

Comment: @J.M. - a guy could have a nice SE reputation just following you around and writing up your comment answers lol - I did basically the same as you but without the `Module`

Comment: Actually, the bigger mistake (that neither you seems to have mentioned) is that I have `OptionValue[Label] == None` whereas you have `OptionValue[Label] === None`.  That seems to the underlying cause of my issues...

Comment: @JP-Ellis, we just didn't want to embarrass you (slow day around here, is why I'm cracking wise)

Comment: @JP, I was trying to be both subtle and didactic, for my part. ;)